# Apache HTTPD: Proxy url pattern to another server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxy

I'm using an apache HTTPD server as a front, and want to redirect certain urls to another server running locally.

For instance I want:

`http://www.example.com/index.php` to load the file located at `/var/www/index.php`
`http://www.example.com/products/*`proxied to another local server & url, e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:9000/`

I'm trying to write a simple `.htaccess` file in the root `www` directory, but whenever I do this simple example, it gives me a `File does not exist` error in the httpd log:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test.html$ /index.php
```

I tried to lookup this error, but all the references online are out of date.  For instance, [mod_rewrite error: [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510829/mod-rewrite-error-client-127-0-0-1-file-does-not-exist) references `httpd.conf` which is no longer included with apache httpd.

Does anyone know why `mod_rewrite` isn't working? or how to write a redirect to another local server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse proxy, you need to use the `P` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^/?products/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:9000/$1 [L,P]
```

You need to have mod_proxy loaded for this to work, otherwise it'll redirect the browser instead.